# loading scripts in a defined order in rails app. how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I noticed that some jquery effects requires that scripts are loaded in proper order.. in my case it is working if they are loaded like this:

```
jquery 1.4.4
jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
autocomplete-rails.js
jquery.cycle.all.js
....
```

if they load in different way then some of my animation or jquery feature is not working. So how do I specify in rails wich script to load first?
Right now I did it in a primitive way by adding 1 2 3 numbers in front of names of every script I have in order that I need resulting in:

```
1jquery 1.4.4
2jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
3autocomplete-rails.js
4jquery.cycle.all.js
```

It's primitive but it's working. Is there another way of doing it?

**Rails 3**

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: I don't understand... your first example is working? They should load in the order that you tell it to, just like in your first example.

Comment: no, in the first example I specified in wich order I need them to load and in second I just show how I force them to load in this order, but I want to know if there is any over more civilised way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: Which version of Rails 3? The answer could be very different between Rails 3.0 and 3.1. For 3.1, simply including them with `javascript_include_tag` in the proper order will work fine. In rails 3.1 since everything is consolidated into one JS file, it shouldn't matter, however I'm not complete sure on that.

Comment: Correction: Rails 3.0 for the `javascript_include_tag` example.

Comment: all right, thanks, I just thought that there is only include :all and include :defaults tag in rails. thanks.I should've searched more on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rails 3.0:

`javascript_include_tag` takes an array of sources, and includes them in the order that you define. You can omit `:defaults`, or define it in your `application.rb` file with `config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(foo.js bar.js)`. `:all` includes all the javascripts in your /javascripts/ folder.

Therefore, it's best to have jQuery at the beginning, since most or all of your javascript files will use jQuery.

More documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/JavascriptTagHelpers/javascript_include_tag